# Auto Completar do chrome preenche campos errados

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, css

Tenho uma aplicação WEB que faz consultas dinamicamente utilizando SQL. Após a atualização do chrome, todos os inputs do sistema estão vindo com o nome do usuário já preenchido.

Exemplo: `value = 'SUPERVISOR'` sendo que o value deveria estar em branco.

Alguém sabe como resolver isso?

Aqui Vai parte do Código

```js
//Função click para buscar dados
$("#formConsult").submit(function(){
  newQry();
  return false;
})

//Função que faz a query
function newQry(){
  var thisButton = $("#loadAll");
  thisButton.button('loading');
  var id_consult = $("#loadAll").attr("data-id");
  var input_array       = new Array();
    var type_input        = new Array();
    var name_paramers     = new Array();
    var newParamers_array = new Array();
    var sql = "";

    if(id_consult !== 0){
      if(allConsult_array.length > 0){
        for(var key = 0; key < allConsult_array.length; key++){
          var consult = allConsult_array[key];
          if(consult.ID_Consulta_Dinamica == id_consult){
            sql = consult.Sql;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    //to check if exists paramers
   $('#boxParamers input').each(function(i, elem){
      input_array.push($(elem).val());
      type_input.push($(elem).attr('name'));
      name_paramers.push($(elem).attr('data-nameParamers'));
   })



   if($(input_array).length > 0){

      for(var key in input_array){

        if(type_input[key] == 'data'){

          var date = input_array[key].split("/");

          var new_date = date[2]+"-"+
                         date[1]+"-"+
                         date[0];
            newParamers_array.push(new_date);


            if(key == 0){//begin if
                sql = sql.replace('{D_(DE)}', "'" + newParamers_array[key] + "'");
              }//end if
              if(key > 0){//begin if
                sql = sql.replace('{D_(ATE)}', "'" + newParamers_array[key] + "'");
              }//end if

        }//end if


        else if(type_input[key] == "periodo"){//begin else if
          newParamers_array.push(input_array[key]);

             for (var i = 0; i < name_paramers.length; i++) {
                var p = newParamers_array[i];
                p = p.replace('-', '');
                p = p.replace('-', '');

                var numero = /^[0-9]+$/;
                p = p.match(numero); 
                if(p !== null){
                  sql = sql.replace('{' + name_paramers[i] + '}', "'" + newParamers_array[i] + "'");
                }else{
                  sql = sql.replace('{' + name_paramers[i] + '}', "'%" + newParamers_array[i] + "%'");
                }
                  sql = sql.replace('{'+name_paramers[i]+'(AAAAMM)}', "'"+newParamers_array[i]+"'");
              }
        }

      }

     buscaQuery(sql);

   }else{
      //to send sql
      buscaQuery(sql);
   }

}


//Função que faz a consulta sql
function buscaQuery(sql){
  $.ajax({//begin function
    url: api,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data:{
      request: "sendSQL",
      sql:     sql,
    },
    success: function(response){
      $("#loadAll").button('reset');
      switch(response.status){
        case 0:
          messageError();
        break;

        case 1:
          allData = response.response;
          dataGridTable(response.response);
        break;

        case 2:
          messageErrorSQL(response.response)
        break;
      }
    },
    error: function(status, xhr, error){
      $("#loadAll").button('reset');
      messageErrorAll(xhr,error, status);
      console.log(status);
      console.log(xhr);
      console.log(error);
    },//end error function
  })//end ajax function
}

//Função que Faz a Grid (DATAGRID DEVEXTREME)
function dataGridTable(consult){

  $("#gridContainer").remove();
  $("#autoExpand").remove();
  $(".options").remove();
  $("#expandlle").remove();

  var moeda         = "";
  var quantidade    = ""; 
  var contagem      = "";
  var cols          = new Array();
  var column        = new Array();
  var teste = new Array();
  var sum_total = new Array();
//Colunas
  for(var key in consult[0]){
    teste.push(key);

    column = 
    {
      dataField: key,
      caption: key,
      customizeText: function (options){
        var  col = this.dataField;
        var type = "";

        if(col !== undefined && col !== null && $.trim(col) !== "" && $.trim(col) !== ""){//begin if

          if(col.match(/V(?=_)/)){//begin if
            type = 0;//moeda
          }//end if

          if(col.match(/Q(?=_)/)){//begin if
            type = 1;//quantidade
          }//end if

          if(!col.match(/Q(?=_)/) && !col.match(/V(?=_)/)){
            //Verifica se a coluna é do tipo Data

            if(col.match(/DATA/)){
              type = 2;
            }else{
              type = 3;
            }
          }

        }else{//begin else
          return options.value;
        }//end else

        switch(type){

          case 0:
            return formatValueCol("moeda",options);
          break;

          case 1:
           return formatValueCol("quantidade",options);
          break;

          case 2:
            return options.value;
          break;

          case 3:
            return options.value;
          break;

        }
      },
      cellTemplate: function (container, options) {
          type = "";

        if(options.column.caption.match(/V(?=_)/)){
          type = "moeda";
        }

        if(options.column.caption.match(/Q(?=_)/)){
          type = "quantidade";
        }

        if(options.column.caption.match(/C(?=_)/)){
          type = "contagem";
        }

        if(!options.column.caption.match(/V(?=_)/) && !options.column.caption.match(/Q(?=_)/) && !options.column.caption.match(/C(?=_)/)){//begin if
          type = "string";
        }//end if

          return formatValueDateCount(type,container,options);

      }//end funtion
    }

    cols.push(column);

    if(key.match(/V(?=_)/)){//begin if
        moeda =
        {
            column:  key,
            summaryType: "sum",
            customizeText:function(options){
              return formatValue("moeda",options);
            }
          };

        sum_total.push(moeda);   
    }//end if

    if(key.match(/Q(?=_)/)){
      quantidade =  
      {
            column: key,
            summaryType: "sum",
            customizeText:function(options){//begin function
              return formatValue("quantidade",options);
            }//end function
          },
      sum_total.push(quantidade); 
    }

    if(key.match(/C(?=_)/)){
      contagem = 
      {
            column: key,
            summaryType: "count",
            customizeText:function(options){//begin function
              return formatValue("contagem",options);
            }//end function
      }
      sum_total.push(contagem); 
    }

  }


    $(".gridAllData").append("<div id='gridContainer' style = 'max-height: 500px;'></div>");
//Grid Comum
   $("#gridContainer").dxDataGrid({
        dataSource: consult,
        allowColumnReordering: true,
        allowColumnResizing: true,
        columnResizingMode: "widget",
        columnAutoWidth: true,
        showColumnLines: true,
        showRowLines: true,
        rowAlternationEnabled: true,
        showBorders: true,
        cellHintEnabled: true,
        noDataText: "Sem Registros",
        height: '100%',
        "export": {
            enabled: true,
            fileName: "Consulta Dinamica",
            allowExportSelectedData: false,
            texts:{
              exportAll: "Exportar Dados",
            },
        },
        grouping: {
            autoExpandAll: false,
            texts:{
              groupContinuedMessage: "Continua na Página Anterior",
              groupContinuesMessage: "Continua na Próxima Página",
            }
        },
        pager: {
            showPageSizeSelector: true,
            allowedPageSizes: [5,10,20,50,100],
            showInfo: true,
            infoText: "Página {0} de {1} ({2} Itens)",
        },  
        paging: {
             pageSize: 10
        },
        groupPanel: {
            visible: true,
            emptyPanelText: "Arraste o cabeçalho de uma coluna aqui para agrupar por essa coluna.",
        },
        columnChooser: {
            enabled: true,
            emptyPanelText: "Arraste uma coluna aqui para escondê-la!",
            mode: "dragAndDrop",
            title: "Esconder Colunas!"
        },
         //Opções de Filtro
        filterRow: {
          visible: true,
          applyFilter: "auto",
          betweenEndText: "Data Inicial", 
          betweenStartText: "Data Final",
          resetOperationText: "Limpar",
          operationDescriptions: 
          { 
            between: "Entre", 
            contains: "Contém", 
            endsWith: "Termina com", 
            equal: "É igual a", 
            greaterThan: "Maior que", 
            greaterThanOrEqual: "Maior ou Igual a", 
            lessThan: "Menor que", 
            lessThanOrEqual: "MEnor ou Igual a", 
            notContains: "Não Contém", 
            notEqual: "Não é igual", 
            startsWith: "Começa com" 
          }, 
          showAllText: "(Todos)",
        },
        headerFilter: {
            visible: true,
            texts:
            {
              cancel: "Cancelar",
              emptyValue: "(Sem Registro)",
              ok: "Ok",
              cancel: "Cancelar",
              emptyValue: "(Sem Registro)",
              ok: "Ok",
              showAllText: "(Mostrar Todos)",
            },
        },

        columns: cols,
        summary: {
          totalItems: sum_total,
          groupItems: sum_total,
        }
    })

}
```

```html
<form id = 'formConsult'>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-5">
   <select class="form-control" id = "selectAllConsult" name="selectAllConsult"> 
   </select>                 
  </div>
  <div id = 'boxParamers' style="display: none;"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <button type="submit" data-id = "" class="btn btn-primary" id="loadAll" data-loading-text="<i class='fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin'></i> Carregando"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Buscar</button>
   </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Coloque o seu código ou parte dele para que possamos analisar.

Comment: Você tentou adicionar o a propriedade `autocomplete="off"` em seus inputs? Inclua o seu html, existem outros fatores que podem influenciar nesse comportamento.

Comment: Sim... o Chrome ignora esse atributo...

Comment: <input autocomplete="off" class="dx-texteditor-input" type="text" spellcheck="false" role="textbox" tabindex="0" style="text-align: left;"> e mesmo assim vem preenchido

Comment: Alguém ja conseguiu uma boa solução para este Chrome que vive fazendo o que ele quer?... Estou com problema de que o crome preenche campos nada a ver... mesmo em maquinas que não tiveram acesso a pagina ainda... será os nomes de campos? Ja tentei mudar e nada.